# Why aren't my rows centered & containing 3 images each?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am creating a web app using Bootstrap 4. Whenever I try and create two rows of 3 images (using Bootstraps rows class and the col-lg-6, etc), the rows are both offset from the center, and not taking up the full columns. I will include an image for reference.

What am I doing incorrectly?

[Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioEWq.jpg)

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="text-center" style="padding: 0px; font-size: 25px;">
        <a class="ins-ic mr-3" role="button" href="https://www.instagram.com/meachwellness/" target="_blank">Follow Me On Instagram  <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/meachwellness/" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 thumb">
              <img id="img-1" src=https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/100793236_309846580171027_6339133455916718389_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=VGXmOlICiXgAX_3Su8z&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&oh=2eae9cdca184910f526a92df6f818805&oe=5F577D9A class="image rounded float-left" alt="..." style="width: 250px; height: 250px; object-fit: cover;">
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/meachwellness/" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 thumb">
              <img id="img-1" src=https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/94751395_114199943384141_875238855374942114_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=53eSQv_S12YAX9nihYy&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&oh=ae42926f97b49e70f5c5b8cc59c86c0f&oe=5F5909FB class="image rounded float-left" alt="..." style="width: 250px; height: 250px; object-fit: cover;">
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/meachwellness/" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 thumb">
              <img id="img-1" src=https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/82718694_796794264120245_396641677005846547_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=2lBpQZZWhkIAX_kX2rG&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&oh=d8a7c1474f6434cab5fe7c224eb14bc9&oe=5F590740 class="image rounded float-left" alt="..." style="width: 250px; height: 250px; object-fit: cover;">
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/meachwellness/" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 thumb">
              <img id="img-1" src=https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/79307404_531685410779846_6162666899133503165_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=oN5cGCUMoyoAX_4qcGV&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&oh=4e83bfe7d58056f17071f04bf7817a14&oe=5F56089B class="image rounded float-left" alt="..." style="width: 250px; height: 250px; object-fit: cover;">
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/meachwellness/" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 thumb">
              <img id="img-1" src=https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/82753023_1032181673805443_398773380568275504_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=bk_PvsocLJMAX8nKDKG&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&oh=223c553739090a16218d12ca406b4aa0&oe=5F58AEF1 class="image rounded float-left" alt="..." style="width: 250px; height: 250px; object-fit: cover;">
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/meachwellness/" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 thumb">
              <img id="img-1" src=https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/79961640_169449397794681_2497375706846442871_n.jpg?_nc_cat=109&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=GTgJ1lhq_-cAX9EtSog&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&oh=c72e68bd61ad8bb3ae0416504327fd95&oe=5F57A1E2 class="image rounded float-left" alt="..." style="width: 250px; height: 250px; object-fit: cover;">
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Btw, I know the image ids shouldn't all be the same. I don't know why they are like that, but it may be because the html is created by JavaScript code and there is some kind of error in there

Comment: Come on. Don't put a `container` inside a `row`. Do it the opposite way.

Comment: Still didn't fix it. Still is offset from the center. @DavidLiang

Comment: Your columns `<div class="col-lg-* />` should be right after `<div class="row" />`. And then you put the anchor tags inside the column. Please read the Bootstrap documentation first before coding.